Hyper-V: Is it possible to use Azure IP with a local VM?
Would it be possible to use an Azure Public IP (for example) and somehow associate it with my VM on my server (not hosted on Azure)?
I'm quite new to networking and I'm not really sure if what I am trying to achieve is possible as I can't find anything which helps answer my question.

Can you explain your use case?


Would it be possible to use an Azure Public IP (for example) and somehow
associate it with my VM on my server (not hosted on Azure)?

Yes. Run it to a router on the Azure VM, then reverse NAT via a tunnel to your local VM. You should also ask first whether you need that - i.e. there are other and free avenues to i.e. host a website at home via a cloudflare zero trust tunnel.

I'm quite new to networking

Superuser.com  - we deal here with professionals.

This question would likely be off topic on Superuser. SU is about issues with end user computing, primarily. It is not about simple/entry-level sysadmin questions.

Yeah, but really, not knowing the basics+ of networking is a real problem here - going through that as a solution is quite tricky and way outside of what we do here. There is a point where "hire an admin" is appropriate.

Definitely. Just pointing out the Q would not really be welcomed on SU either. It needs research and self effort. I'd guess a web search would show how to do this, or why not to do this, pretty well.
